# How can I modify the height of selected tab?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can modify the height of the unselected tab by modifying the height of container, but I cannot modify the height of the selected tab.

So the height of the tabs in both cases cannot be made the same like this image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECqN5.png

How can I make it the same?

```
tabBar() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: TabBar(
        isScrollable: true,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
        unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          color: Color(0xFF000000),
        ),
        labelStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
          color: Color(0xFFffffff),
        ),
        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
        indicator: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: const Color(0xFF000000),
        ),
        tabs: [
          Tab(
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              .
              .
              .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting height to the child of Tab, there are two ways to resolve this issue.

1. Set height of the TabBar with SizedBox.

```
SizedBox(
  height: 40,
  child: TabBar(tabs: [
    ...
  ]),
)
```

2. Or set height of each Tab.

```
Tab(
  height: 40,
  child: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    ),
    child: Center(child: Text('foo')),
  ),
)
```

For the second case, you will have to match the height of all tabs which will produce redundant code, I recommend following the first case unless you need variation for certain tabs.